# Understanding and, or operations in Python

Tags: python

I am trying some operations in Python but I am not understanding the underlying concept of it. I tried various combinations which might be bit tough for you but my objective was how it is working internally in Python.Please find the code below:

```
>>> 2 or 3
2
>>> 3 or 2
3
>>> 3 or 3
3
>>> 3 or -3
3
>>> -3 or 3
-3
>>> 0 or 3
3
>>> 0 or -9
-9
>>> 3 and 4
4
>>> 3 and 6
6

>>> 0 or None
>>> 0 and None
0
>>> None and 0
>>> None or 0
0


>>> 5 and 2
2
>>> -3 and 6
6
>>> 3 and -6
-6
>>> 3 and 0
0
>>> 0 and 0
0
>>> 0 and 0.0
0
>>> 0.0 and 0
0.0
>>> 0.0 or 0
0
>>> 0 or 0.0
0.0
>>> [] or 3
3
>>> 3 or []
3
>>> 0 or []
[]
>>> [] or 0
0
>>> [] and 3
[]
>>> 3 and []
[]
>>> [] or {}
{}
>>> [] and {}
[]
>>> [] and {}
[]
>>> {} or []
[]
>>> {} and []
{}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for future questions

Comment: It appears there's no question in this question. What do you expect us to do; do you want us to post a full explanation of how the logical operators work? There are plenty of those readily available. I doubt the internet would benefit from having _another one_ of those.

Comment: Thanks to those who answered the question rather than ppl who simply commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually very well described in most tutorials; the general rule is: `a and b` is `b` if `a` is true, else it is `a`; `a or b` is `a` if `a` is true, else it is `b`. Now, `False`, `None`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `''`, `0` and `0.0` are all considered false; practically everything else is true.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to how truth tables work here. See the following link:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Boolean_Expressions

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is short-circuiting in action:

- `a and b`

  - `a` is `False` -> `a` immediately returned
  - `a` is `True`, `b` is `False` -> `b` immediately returned
  - both `True` -> the last object is returned (`b`)
- `a or b`

  - `a` is `True` -> `a` is immediately returned
  - `a` is `False`, `b` is `True` -> `b` is returned
  - both `False` -> the last object returned (`b`)

Now, some values are considered 'falsey', e.g. `bool(value) == False`, for example:

- `False` itself
- the number zero (`0, 0.0, 0 + 0j`)
- empty containers (`[], tuple(), "", {}, set()`)
- `None`
- anything else whose `__bool__` method returns `False`

Others are considered 'truthy'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting `and` and `or` to produce a boolean value, that is, `True` or `False`. But they don't. `or` will return the first operand if that evaluates to `True`; otherwise it will return the second operand. `and` will return the first operand if that evaluates to `False`; otherwise it will return the second operand. For the evaluation, the following count as `False`: zero integers and floats, the empty string, and empty tuples, lists and dicts. Anything else counts as `True`, including, for example, the string `"0"`.